# Unable to restart my apache2 server Error : order takes only one argument allow deny deny allow' or 'mutual-failure'

Tags: apache-2.2, apache2

whenever I try to restart my server I get the following error.

`order takes only one argument allow deny deny allow' or 'mutual-failure'`

My `000-default.config` looks like this

```
<Directory /var/www/html/>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny From All
</Directory>
```

I don't exactly know how this conf works, and I don't remember how it fas earlier.

Upon search I got to know that there is a space issue `deny, allow`. After changing that also I am still getting error.

**Edit**
I am getting this error for the above `Directory`

```
(98) Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98) Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
```

Comment: you run already something on port 80, dont you read the error?

Comment: I read that and was able to make it work after researching a more. Thank you.